# Cross Domain AJAX query

Tags: javascript, jquery, same-origin-policy

With the help of Stack overflow I currently have this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WskJT/

I have an aspx file on another server (cannot access this, so amendments to that server are not an option) and *offline* (php include not an option) I would have a page that pulls this data & removes columns as per the above fiddle.

Is there any workaround to be able to get this data from the aspx file & display (something similar to) the output the the above fiddle?

I'm an enthusiastic novice so I apologise if I haven't worded this correctly etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there's a file on a server, but you can't manipulate the server, then that sounds like *someone else* has a file on the server, not you. The inability to do cross-domain requests is a security measure. If it was simple to circumvent, then it wouldn't be much use.

Comment: @amnotiam The file is on our intranet at work, it has various stats about all the departments but we just need our stats in real time.

Comment: The fact that it's on a local network at work doesn't change the security aspect. Either the data is available for public consumption, or it isn't. If not, the server needs to make it available by some means. You won't be able to directly access it unless the targeted content is hosted on the same domain as your page, or your page is on a more specific domain within the domain that contains the targeted data. For example, if the data is accessible via `foobar.com`, and your page is hosted at `mypage.foobar.com`, then there's a workaround available.

Comment: @amnotiam Thanks for the info. It just kind of baffles me because I can open the page in Chrome and view the data, but I can't copy the data to my own page - but if I was online, I could have a php include, then manipulate the data as much as I want. Crazy stuff :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the server being on your intranet as you have indicated in your comments you will face security issues as pointed out.  What you could do is create a 'proxy' web service in the same domain as your main page.

Start by creating a 'service.php' file on your own server.  From there, make the necessary [curl](https://www.php.net/curl) calls to the ASPX page on the other server.  Any time service.php (or call it proxy.php if you like) is called, it in turn calls the ASPX page, with any parameters as required.  Have it read the output text and return the text to the caller itself.

Point your AJAX code to the 'service.php' file.

Now your javascript calls are in the same domain and you shouldn't have the permission problems you were facing with the JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I'm afraid we can't access the server to make amendments that end (asking IT, long, slow, not happening). I also can't do this on my paid-for server space because its company confidential information. I was hoping to be able to store a html file on our shared hard drive so we could view the data without having to see the other columns. Before all of this I thought about just using a number of iframes to point and look at specific parts of the page which is a technically possible solution but very ugly.